# how to fix page redirection by useing functions

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

The problem is that I am trying to add `?page=mypage` to my sidebar.
First I've added this to `.htaccess`:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and this is my sidebar:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidebar d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="sidebar-logo">
        <img src="path/to/your/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php?page=dashboard">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=settings">
                    <i class="fa fa-settings"></i> Settings
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=users">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-users"></i> Users
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Add more sidebar menu items as needed -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-auto"></div> <!-- Empty div to push the sidebar to the bottom -->
</div>
```

and this is the function that control's the `?page=`:

```
function include_page() {
    $allowedPages = array('error', 'dashboard', 'settings', 'users');

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];

        // Validate and sanitize the requested page
        if (!in_array($page, $allowedPages)) {
            // Invalid page, redirect to a default page or show an error message
            header('Location: index.php?page=error');
            exit;
        }

        $filePath = __DIR__ . '/pages/' . $page . '.php';

        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            include($filePath);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Handle error: page not found
    header('Location: index.php?page=error');
    exit;
}
```

and I've added this to my `index.php`:

```
include_page();
```

It does not allow me to go to `index.php` or any page its always redirect me to `index.php?page=error`.

I've tried everything and nothing is able to resolve the issue.

I tried to remove the error page but it is still the same results.

**problem solved**

```
function handlePageRequest($page)
{
    if ($page === 'index' || $page === '') {
        // Actions for the dashboard page
        include("index.php"); // Include the dashboard file
        // Other actions specific to the dashboard page
    } elseif ($page === 'dashboard') {
        // Actions for the dashboard page
        include("pages/dashboard.php"); // Include the dashboard file
        // Other actions specific to the dashboard page
    } elseif ($page === 'settings') {
        // Actions for the settings page
        include("pages/settings.php"); // Include the settings file
        // Other actions specific to the settings page
    } elseif ($page === 'users') {
        // Actions for the users page
        include("pages/users.php"); // Include the users file
        // Other actions specific to the users page
    } else {
        // Invalid page or 404 error
        include("error/404.php"); // Include the 404 file
    }

    exit(); // Prevent further execution of the script
}

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
handlePageRequest($page);
```

and sidebar

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidebar d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="sidebar-logo">
        <img src="path/to/your/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'dashboard') !== false) echo 'active'; ?>" href="index.php?page=dashboard">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'settings') !== false) echo 'active'; ?>" href="index.php?page=settings">
                    <i class="fa fa-settings"></i> Settings
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'users') !== false) echo 'active'; ?>" href="index.php?page=users">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-users"></i> Users
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Add more sidebar menu items as needed -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-auto"></div> <!-- Empty div to push the sidebar to the bottom -->
</div>
```

Comment: What if you hit the URL: `index.php?page='dashboard'`? Where does it take you? Also I do not see an entry for `sidebar` for `$allowedPages`.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you need/want that RewriteRule for. It will rewrite anything to `index.php?page=$1`, which would allow you to have urls like `/dashboard`, `/settings` etc. _without_ the need for `index.php`. Did you print out `$_GET['page']` in your script, I'd guess it is something like `index.php...`, thus _not_ in your `$allowedPages`.

Comment: Sachin Bahukhandi it does not allow me to go anyy where its only show me The page isn’t redirecting properly even if i try to go to index.php.

Comment: brombeer what do you mean by  print out $_GET['page']

Comment: <div>Current Page: <?php echo $_GET['page']; ?></div>  ?

Comment: Yes, what does it output?

Comment: nothing because i cant view the index.php at all only a "The page isn’t redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

Comment: while am trying to fix the code i found out the $_GET['page']; isnt working  "Warning: Undefined array key "page"" am gonna try to figure it out

Comment: Using a rewrite rule such as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]` generally conflicts with using querystring-based pages such as `index.php?page=dashboard`. The former is usually used for "pretty URLs" such as `/dashboard/`. If you don't want pretty URLs, then you probably don't need the rewrite rule, native Apache/PHP will work just fine. If you want pretty URLs, you need to use them in your HTML, the htaccess file is only part of the equation.